# What are the different buffs of Titania's Tribute and their effects

Tags: warframe

What are the different buff that can be obtained using Titania's Tribute (2) and what are their effects ?

This informations does not seem available at all in the Warframe wiki or in a Steam guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DUST TRIBUTE**
The Dust aura reduces the accuracy of enemies within 30 meters around Titania by 10% for 120 seconds. Each additional stack will increase the effect by 10%, up to a maximum of 50% reduced enemy accuracy.

Enemy accuracy reduction, aura radius and duration are not affected by Power Strength, Power Range and Power Duration, respectively.
Enemies affected visually emit energy butterflies, affected by Titania's energy color.

Given by ranged enemies, such as Lancers or Crewmen.

**THORNS TRIBUTE**
The Thorns aura will reflect 5% of the damage taken back to the attacker, up to 40 meters away, for 120 seconds. Each additional stack will increase the effect by 5%, up to a maximum of 25% damage reflection. Any allies within 35 meters around Titania will also benefit from Thorns' damage reflection.

Damage reflection, aura and ally buff radii, and duration are not affected by Power Strength, Power Range and Power Duration, respectively.
Allies and enemies affected visually emit energy butterflies, affected by Titania's energy color.

Given by melee enemies, such as Prod Crewmen and Chargers.

**ENTANGLE TRIBUTE**
The Entangle aura slows down enemy movement within 10 meters around Titania by 5% for 120 seconds. Each additional stack will increase the effect by 5%, up to a maximum of 25% slower enemy movement.

Enemy movement debuff, aura radius and duration are not affected by Power Strength, Power Range and Power Duration, respectively.
Enemies affected visually emit energy butterflies, affected by Titania's energy color.

Given by heavy enemy units, such as Bombards and Ancient Disruptors.

**FULL MOON TRIBUTE**
The Full Moon aura increases the damage companions deal by 15% for 90 seconds. Each additional stack will increase the effect by 15%, up to a maximum of 75% increased companion damage. Any teammates within 30 meters around Titania will also benefit from Full Moon's effects, increasing their respective companions' damage.

Companion damage bonus, ally buff radius and duration are not affected by Power Strength, Power Range and Power Duration, respectively.

Given by summoned enemies (such as Hyekka) and flying enemies (such as Leech Ospreys).

all of this was available on the wiki http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Titania/Abilities

Comment: Well thanks, the wiki didn't include these informations at the time I asked the question. Thanks anyway.